# LINQ select where EF Navigation property value in array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, navigation-properties

I have a Web API method that is used to search a EF object named 'Patients'. The patient has a navigation property named Referrals (one patient can have many referrals) and each Referral has an integer property named 'ConsultantID'.

I would like to return all patients who have referrals whose ConsultantID value is within a defined array named 'consultants' but i can't get my head around the logic needed. I have the below at the moment but it isn't working as i expected, the Referrals.Any call seems to be performing an 'Exists' call rather than the join behaviour i was expecting.

```
public List<HelperCode.DTO.SearchResult> SearchPatients(string firstname, string surname, [FromUri] int[] consultants)
        {
            IQueryable<Patient> results = db.Patients;

            List<HelperCode.DTO.SearchResult> output = new List<HelperCode.DTO.SearchResult>();

            List<int> inputConsultants = consultants.OfType<int>().ToList();


            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname)) { results = db.Patients.Where(c => c.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(firstname.ToLower())); }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(surname)) { results = results.Where(c => c.Surname.ToLower().Contains(surname.ToLower())); }


            if (consultants.Length > 0) { 
                results = results.Where(c => c.Referrals.Any(r => inputConsultants.Contains(r.ConsultantID ?? default(int)))); 
            }


            results = results.OrderBy(i => i.Surname);

            foreach (Patient p in results) {
                output.Add(new HelperCode.DTO.SearchResult(p));
            }

            return output;
        }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this line `consultants.OfType<int>().ToList()`?

Comment: Why do you care if the SQL query is using `EXISTS` or `JOIN`? Are you getting correct results? If so, what is the problem?

Comment: @Ric It is purely to convert the consultants array into a list in order to later call the .Contains method on it.

Comment: but you take an int array, filtering the elements to only return ints, then calling `ToList()`....

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't care. It seems to be restricting the result set. If i pass it a single Consultant ID value in the array it returns 220 results but if i pass in that same ID and another 3 Consultant ID's it only returns 28 - i want it to return ANY result that has a referral with a ConsultantID in the array so would expect more not less results.

Comment: So it's an incorrect result issue. Can you post the EF generated SQL? I'm asking because your query looks good.

Comment: @IvanStoev More like an incorrect developer issue. I made a change to my client script which when multiple Consultants were selected resulted in the API method being passed a array with a single value of 0 (for those interested the request string was ?consultants=14,56,103 when it should have been ?consultants=14&consultants=56&consultants=103). Thanks for the help, it was only when i re-ran SQL profiler i noticed it was executing the same query when multiple were selected as it was when one was selected but with a value of 0 instead of the actual ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Developer's a tool, code works fine but input values were incorrect. Hopefully will be of use to someone down the line.